# When calling recv() the program works very slowly

Tags: response, winsock, python-idle, recv, performance

My code is: http://ideone.com/nVXIQ.

`recv()` functions always idling (it works very slow); it takes several seconds to get the result, and `recv()` should handle quickly such small amount of data.

Comment: Because I'm too stupid to see that you just created a new user account and re-posted an identical question.

Answer (score 2):

Is your question about recv's blocking behavior? If so, then investigate using non-blocking IO with something like a select/poll loop.

Comment: no, my question is exactly about recv() work in my code, because I'm not understanding why does it work slow/idle?

Comment: @user167908: Why do you think it is slow?  How do you know it is slow?  Why do you keep using the word "idle"?  Only blocking functions cause a program to "idle", and you say this isn't about `recv`'s blocking behavior.